# PHP foreach loop x times and add placeholder

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am using a foreach to loop through image. There are maximum four images and minimum 1 image.
For example if there are two image (= two loops) i want to tell the foreach he needs to loop two times again and echo some placeholder pictures.

Heres my foreach:

```
<?php foreach($users as $k => $v) {?>
<img src="/images/user_<?php echo $k; ?>.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<?php } ?>
```

Outputs (two loops):

```
<img src="/images/user_0.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<img src="/images/user_1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

but the new script should output:

```
<img src="/images/user_0.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<img src="/images/user_1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<img src="/images/user_placeholder.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<img src="/images/user_placeholder.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

dont forget its possible that $users can have x entries (0-4)

Comment: So you want x number of user images to be output to the browser, and x number of placeholders (thus far all identical) immediately after them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to fill an array with as many items as needed (since they are all going to be identical) and then print them out.

```
<?php foreach($users as $k => $v) {?>
<img src="/images/user_<?php echo $k; ?>.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<?php } ?>

<?php
echo implode('', array_fill(0, count($users), 'placeholder image HTML'));
```

Of course instead of this cuteness you could also use another `foreach` that prints `placeholder image HTML` in each iteration.

**Update:** It turns out there's an even better method:

```
echo str_repeat('placeholder image HTML', count($users));
```

PHP really has *too* many functions to remember. :)

Comment: thanks for this cute solution :) *accept* ... edit: both worked. And i like one-line solutions so im double happy

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter...

```
<?php
$counter = 0; 
foreach($users as $k => $v) {?> 
    <img src="/images/user_<?php echo $k; ?>.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<?php $counter++;  
} 
while{$counter < 4)
{?>
    <img src="/images/user_placeholder.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$count = 1;
foreach($users as $k => $v) {
?>
    <img src="/images/user_<?php echo $k; ?>.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<?php 
    $count++;
} 

for ($i = $count; $i <= 4; $i++) {
?>
    <img src="/images/user_placeholder.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<?php 
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$placeholders = array();
foreach($users as $k => $v) {?>
    <img src="/images/user_<?php echo $k; ?>.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <?php 
    $placeholders[] = '<img src="/images/user_placeholder.jpg" alt="" title="" />';
} 
foreach ($placeholders as $placeholder){
    echo $placeholder;
} ?>
```

As you can see, there are a dozen ways to skin this particular cat.