# PHP loop x number of times, using while and if

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement, while-loop

So this has been driving me nuts for several days.  I've tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672062/php-loop-x-amount-of-times) and [THAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335913/php-foreach-loop-x-times-and-add-placeholder) but nothing is working.  Here's the basic rundown:

I have a MySQL database with 200 or so locations.  The user enters their zip code, and I want to give them 6 random locations within 100 miles of home.  Everything works great, except I can't get it to limit the results to 6.  It will give me ALL the results for <100.  When I try the code below (adding the `for ($x=0...)` bit), I get the same result, only each one repeats 6 times before listing the next one.  Here's the pertinent code that returns all the locations. Any help would save me from throwing my computer out the window.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY RAND()"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbase2);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

$city = $row['city']; 
$id= $row['id'];
$miles = calculateDistance($lat, $lon, $point2_lat,$point2_lon); 

  if ($miles < "100")
      { for ($x=0; $x<6; $x++){
       echo $city . " is about " . round($miles) . " miles away.<br />";
         };
      };           
  };
```

Like I said, for the sake of this post, I tried to pare it down to the important bits.  Let me know if something vital is missing from my example.

Comment: Looks like you are just looping six times and printing the same thing six times for every city within 100 miles.

Comment: Sidenote: change `if ($miles < "100") {...}` to `if (intval($miles) < 100) {...}`

Comment: selecting everything by order rand() and calculating in php will be  slow. if possible, calculate the distance on the db. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Comment: FuzzyTree, thanks for the link.  My db will max out around 300-400 locations, so I think rand() should be ok, no?  So far, it's plenty fast enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following change should do it:

```
$count = 0;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($count < 6))
    {

    $city = $row['city']; 
    $id= $row['id'];
    $miles = calculateDistance($lat, $lon, $point2_lat,$point2_lon); 

    if ($miles < 100.0) {
       echo $city . " is about " . round($miles) . " miles away.<br />";
       $count = $count + 1;
      };           
  };
```

There are more elegant ways...

Comment: I see what you did there. Seems so simple now that I see it. Works like a charm! Only correction is that line 2 is missing some containers: `while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($count < 6))` Thanks.